# rails 3 Validate presence based off boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, model, validation

I have a model that has a boolean called `draft`

I want to validate presence of fields only if `draft == false`.

my model

```
if self.draft == false
  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :blurb, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 175 }
  validates :category_id, :presence => true
  validates :location_id, :presence => true
  validates :goal, :presence => true
else
end
```

in my controller

```
def new
  @item.new(:draft => false) || @item.new(:draft => true)

def create
  if params[:commit] == "Create Item"
    @cause = Item.new(params[:item], :draft => false)
  elsif params[:commit] == "Save Changes"
    @cause = Item.new(params[:item], :draft => true)
  end
```

It completely ignores my if statement and validates anyways whether it's true or not upon clicking `Save Changes`.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A conditional validation looks like below

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 45 }, :if => :draft_is_false?

private
def draft_is_false?
   draft == false
end
```

Similarly, you can perform conditional validations on other fields and these can be grouped as well. Go through the [Conditional Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) sections on Ruby on Rails guides.

Comment: Conditional Validations link is dead. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner in newer rails syntax:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 45 }, if: -> (item) { item.draft? }
```

Notice that there is a question mark after the draft attribute. Rails automatically create methods like `draft?` for all attributes on a model, and is basically a shortcut for `attr.present?`. When used with Boolean attributes, it suggests that the developer's intention is to check for true/false.